# No use of variable from for loop with range

Tags: python

This piece of code is from a bigger program and builds a random ascii string

Why is the variable `i` used? It is not used anywhere else

Thanks

```
def buildblock(size):
    ascii = ''
    for i in range(0, size):
        a = random.randint(65, 160)
        ascii += chr(a)
    return(ascii)
```

It is used like:

```
buildblock(random.randint(3,10))
```

Comment: Because the author doesn't know the convention.

Comment: They want to write a loop to run a fixed number of times; they use a for loop; the for loop needs a loop variable. It could be called anything. Often it would be called `_` to indicate that it is unused, but any name works fine.

Comment: No, `i` is not used. This code is just interested in the `for .. range(..)` part to loop a certain number of times, but doesn't need the value of `range`. The convention in this case is to use `for _ in ..` to signify that the value is unused.

Comment: Unrelated to the specific question but ASCII is a 7-bit code so values over 127 (decimal) are not ASCII. This function might select ordinals in the range 128-160

Answer (score 1):

You can choose any other name for the loop variable, it's just that any variable is needed for the loop. A common convention in cases where that variable name is not used anywhere else is a simple underscore, `_`.